# how to implement code for barcode and assigning details to textview?

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I implement code for barcode after the barcode image image is captured? How to assign the barcode details to the textview?

I am capturing barcode image but here I have get the details about that image and assign that details to the textview for this how to get the image details?

give the code for details for barcode what i captured.

Comment: I tried to edit this for clarity, but I can't manage to bring it up to our quality standards. If you can improve it, flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking for. It seems you already know how to scan the barcode and retrieve the number from it. You're asking, given the barcode number how to retrieve details about the item. Please  let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is open-source you can use the [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) library.